# Devise for two models: how to customize views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise for two models, and after running `rails g devise:views`, some views are created in views/devise/ -- Some of them are fine and can be shared between those two models, however I have to add some fields (depending on the model) to the registration one.

So for example, for `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` I have this:

### Sign up

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <p><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

This is ok, but how would I make it model specific? How can I tell devise to go look at /views/my_model/new.html.erb?  Basically I want to have two separate registrations/new templates for each model that is using Devise, because each model has different fields.

When I do `rails g devise:views mymodel`, it still renders the templates of `views/devise` instead of `views/mymodel/devise`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a partial containing a form for each of your models with whatever fields you deem necessary.  Name them after the specific models you're using (user, or admin).  Then in devise/registrations/new.html.erb render the appropriate partial depending on resource.class.name.